# test site against low bandwidth?

Tags: jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test a site for low bandwidth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396645/how-to-test-a-site-for-low-bandwidth)

Is there a way to test my site as though it were on a slow interenet connection - I need to simulate a low speed to test how the site reacts

Comment: Didn't you got this while typing your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396645/how-to-test-a-site-for-low-bandwidth?rq=1

Comment: You may also check [this](http://superuser.com/questions/330501/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-firefox)

Comment: I assume that you have a smartphone. Switch 3G off, and load your page.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/ this website analyses your website and outputs loadtime for low bandwidth and some more helpful stuff

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called **Throttle** for Firefox that does just that, you can install it and then throttle the download or upload speed to a certain limit.

The problem is that the creators of the plugin stopped supporting it, but there is this unofficial modified version http://www.mediafire.com/?oqkcqdc0c8be4ll that works with newer versions of Firefox.